# Does Jenkins work with NativeScript?

Tags: jenkins, nativescript, devops, nativescript-cli

Is it possible to use Jenkins to build NativeScript? I've had an extremely rough time with it. Right now, the problem I'm dealing with is that while tnsbuild works when I run it myself, it doesn't complete with Jenkins. The error is `WARNING: The Java compiler version 10.0.2 is not compatible with the current Android runtime version 3.4.3. In order to use this Javac version, you need to update your Android runtime or downgrade your Java compiler version.`

I looked at the NativeScript source code and couldn't track down this issue to determine where exactly NS is finding the version number, but both my terminal and Jenkins are looking in the same path to for the SDKs.

Comment: The error log indicates that you are using old runtime version (tns-android 3.4.3) while the installed Java is version 10. NativeScript has just recently provided support for Java 10 so either update your project runtime or downgrade the Java  (as suggested in the error log) - notice that we are talking about the Java JDK and not about the Android SDK.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up solving it by setting JAVA_HOME for all of Jenkins and pointing it at my Java 8 installation.